# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply' error

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I have the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'`  when I click on Edit button. Here is my panel :

```
Ext.define(
    "ux.panel.MyPanel", {
    extend : "Ext.form.Panel",
    xtype : "MyPanel",
    title : "Bla bla title"

    initComponent : function () {
        ux.panel.MyPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    },
    init : function (initParameters) {
        this.initParameters = initParameters;

        this.removeAll(true);

        if (this.initParameters == null)
            return;
    },
    editSomething : function () {
        alert("editTV");
    },
    tbar : [{
            text : "Edit"
            iconCls : "silk-edit-16",
            id : "editbutton",
            disabled : false,
            listeners : {
                click : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : this.editSomething
                }
            }
        }, {
            text : "Remove",
            iconCls : "silk-delete-16",
            id : "removeButton",
            disabled : false,
            listeners : {
                click : {
                    scope : this,
                    fn : function () {
                        alert("RemoveTV");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

This panel is included in a page composed of many other panel. I'm doubting that this in the this.editSomething is not pointing to my panel. I don't have any clue about how to deal with this.

Anyone has any idea about the reason please?

Answer (score 2):

That is because `this` is not what you expect it to be.

Add the `tbar` in the `initComponent` function, like:

```
initComponent: function () {
    Ext.apply(this, {
        tbar: [{
            text: "Edit",
            iconCls: "silk-edit-16",
            id: "editbutton",
            disabled: false,
            listeners: {
                click: {
                    scope: this,
                    fn: this.editSomething
                }
            }
        }, {
            text: "Remove",
            iconCls: "silk-delete-16",
            id: "removeButton",
            disabled: false,
            listeners: {
                click: {
                    scope: this,
                    fn: function () {
                        alert("RemoveTV");
                    }
                }
            }
        }]
    });

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gkcU7/